# Does Flex support file write on client's computer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I think I found some example using FileStream [here](http://blog.barncar.com/?p=3). But that was for AIR app, I tried FileStream, it seems doesnt work on my project. Can i use this one or do I need to import extra lib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex is a framework that can be deployed for two different runtimes - AIR or Flash. If you are deploying a browser app, you won't be able to use FileStream as it is only available to AIR. You can use FileReference, though (it will open a file save window and allow user to select the location to download the file).

Comment: so, I need to write the file first on the server and then, let the user download it(though I think that was very expensive). That is very helpful.

Comment: Use the `FileReference.save()` ([docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save())) method if you want to save data from your application's memory to the user's local file system, i.e., to save data locally without first sending it to a server.